# How to access files in a class' path in MATLAB?

Tags: class, matlab, relative-path

I'd like to implement a class which returns the data located in a precalculated data file, e.g.

```
classdef myConstants
  properties ( Constant )
    const1 = load('consts.mat', 'const1');
  end
end
```

However, I want the file `consts.mat` to lie in the `@myConstants` folder which is on the MATLAB path, so I cannot (and should not) hard-code the location.

So how can I instruct `load` to use the file `@myConstants\consts.mat` independently of `@myConstants` actual location?

**edit** I realized if the folder `@myConstants` lies on the MATLAB path, `load consts.mat` works globally. So, the code I wrote already works perfectly fine, **but** `consts.mat` is not only globally accessible, one also has to pay attention to name collisions if other classes provide their own `consts.mat` - which is why I don't post this as an answer, I'd still prefer a solution that does not bear this potential bug source.

Comment: As I understand it, @-folders should not be in the MATLAB path to begin with, which is perhaps the problem.

Comment: @Will Why is that? Should one use +packages instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `consts.mat` in the directory `@myConstants\private`. You may also wish to do this:

```
const1 = getfield( load( 'consts.mat', 'const1' ), 'const1' );
```

because LOAD returns a structure with fields named for the values loaded.

Comment: perfect! and just in time to stop me from [doing it a lot more messy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9600168/321973) :-) (I actually used the `getfield` part, I forgot to put it in my example)

Answer (score 1):

```
const1 = load([fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')) filesep 'consts.mat'], 'const1');
```

does the trick, but it does not hide `consts.mat`